# possibility of setting a seed to retrieve the same order of rows after a combination of df.sample and df.apply

Tags: python-polars

<s>Each time I call `pl.read_csv` on my csv file, the order of rows differ. I guess it's due to the parallelisation. I would like to set a seed to always receive the same order of rows for my tests.</s>

Setting `pl.set_random_seed(0)` did not help. [Docs](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.set_random_seed.html).
Do I have to sort the dataframe to have the same order? Is there a more efficient way? Why does the `set_random_seed` method not work?

I am using `polars = "^0.19.3"`.

#### Update

It is not the read_csv that is changing the order but the combination of these procedures.

```py
def func_to_reproduce(n: int) -> pl.DataFrame:
    file_path = MODULE_DIR / "input.tsv"
    df = pl.read_csv(file_path, separator="\t")

    def select_rows(df):
        # Sample rows
        num_rows = len(df)
        sampled_df = df.sample(min(n, num_rows), seed=0)
        # Add index to the sampled dataframe
        idx_expr = (
            pl.col("fullmtype").cumcount().over(["fullmtype", "etype"]).alias("index")
            + 1
        )
        return sampled_df.with_columns(idx_expr)

    grouped_df = df.groupby(["fullmtype", "etype"]).apply(select_rows)
    return grouped_df
```

Here each time I get a different `grouped_df`. I set the seed for `df.sample`. I also tried `pl.set_random_seed`. Is there something else that I should be aware of?

Comment: Do you have any more info? I have never encountered a different read order with `read_csv`.

Comment: pl.read_csv should return the rows in the order defined. Could you share your csv file by opening in issue? I've never seen this.

Comment: So the issue is partially a false positive. There is still a confusing part that though. Let me update the description.

Comment: You say you have polars 0.19.3 but your code has the old syntax of `groupby` and `apply`. Are you sure you have 0.19.3? In any event, try adding the parameter `maintain_order=True` to your `groupby`.

Comment: I have polars 0.19.3. This syntax is still valid it seems. No I haven't tried `maintain_order=True` let me try.

Comment: Alright `maintain_order` was what I needed, thanks!

Comment: I replaced `apply` with `map_groups`. Was that the syntax change?

Comment: They were renamed in [0.19.0](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/releases/tag/py-0.19.0). `select_rows()` looks similar to: `.agg(pl.all().sample(n, seed=0), index=pl.int_range(1, pl.count() + 1))` - although it seems like `Expr.sample` would need to accept an expression for `n` in order to emulate the `min(n, num_rows)` behaviour. (If it did, I think you would then be able to use `n = pl.min_horizontal(pl.lit(n), pl.count())`?)

Answer (score 0):

It may be worth pointing out that `Expr.sample` now [accepts expressions for `n=`](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/11257)

You should be able to implement your `select_rows` natively as of Polars `0.19.5`

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({
   "A": [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4],
   "B": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
})

n = 2
sample_size = pl.min_horizontal(n, pl.count())

(df.group_by("A")
   .agg(
      pl.all().sample(sample_size, seed=0), 
      pl.int_range(1, sample_size + 1).alias("index")
   )
   .explode(pl.exclude("A"))
)
```

```
shape: (6, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬───────┐
│ A   ┆ B   ┆ index │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---   │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64   │
╞═════╪═════╪═══════╡
│ 1   ┆ 1   ┆ 1     │
│ 1   ┆ 3   ┆ 2     │
│ 2   ┆ 4   ┆ 1     │
│ 3   ┆ 5   ┆ 1     │
│ 4   ┆ 6   ┆ 1     │
│ 4   ┆ 8   ┆ 2     │
└─────┴─────┴───────┘
```